# Why yshift doesn't work in this TikZ example?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Any idea why `yshift` doesn't work in the following TikZ example?

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (B) at (2.5,0);
  \draw (A) -- (B);
  \draw[yshift=2cm] (A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Shifting a line joining nodes in TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/93839/shifting-a-line-joining-nodes-in-tikz)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It would work with coordinates or if you place the yshift inside the parentheses next to the name A and B:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (B) at (2.5,0);
  \draw (A) -- (B);
  \draw ([yshift=2cm]A) -- ([yshift=2cm]B);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks but it looks odd the way yshift is specified. Any idea why?

Comment: Coordinate transformations do not apply to a node. Its anchor remains the same. See section 15.11 of the pgf manual.

Comment: I didn't know that one can apply transformations this way to coordinates (I would have used `($(A) - (0,2cm)$)`) and the calc library.

Comment: Before the calc library `([yshift=2cm]A)` was the only method, now we have the choice.

Comment: I don't understand.  He is transforming a coordinate not node. In the example, A and B are defined with \coordinate.

Answer (score 8):

In such a simple case you can use `transform canvas`:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (B) at (2.5,0);
  \draw (A) -- (B);
  \draw[transform canvas={yshift=2cm}] (A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: Output]

In more complex scenarios make sure to read the warnings in the PGF manual in section *25.4 Canvas Transformations*:

> Canvas transformations should be used with great care. In most circumstances you do not want line widths to change in a picture as this creates visual inconsistency.
>   Just as important, when you use canvas transformations pgf loses track of positions of nodes and of picture sizes since it does not take the effect of canvas transformations into account when it computes coordinates of nodes.

Comment: Don't put some text around that ;)

Answer (score 7):

`yshift` (and similar commands) are applied to all coordinates in the path, not to the path as a whole. They are also not applied to anchors: according to the TikZ manual (section 15.11. in the 2.0 version):

> Once the node x has been defined, you
>   can use (x. anchor ) wherever you
>   would normally use a normal
>   coordinate. This will yield the
>   position at which the given anchor is
>   in the picture. Note that
>   transformations do not apply to this
>   coordinate, that is, (x.north) will be
>   the northern anchor of x even if you
>   have said scale=3 or xshift=4cm. This
>   is usually what you would expect.

Comment: I would have thought that `\draw[yshift=2cm] (0,0) -- (2.5,0);` and `\draw[yshift=2cm] (A) -- (B);`work the same way, since tikz simply subs (A) and (B) with the respective coordinates before doing the drawing.  Note that A and B  are defined to be coordinates not nodes. Where is this explained in the manual?