# Shifting a line joining nodes in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

Consider these squared nodes:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [draw] (A) at (0,0) {demo text};
\node [draw] (B) at (0,-2) {demo text};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I'd like to link them with two offset lines. If A and B were two numeric coordinates, I could do it as simply as that:

```
\draw [xshift=1em]  (0,0) -- (0,-2);
\draw [xshift=-1em] (0,0) -- (0,-2);
```

Unfortunately this code doesn't shift the line at all:

```
\draw [xshift=1em] (A) --(B);
```

After trial and error, I found I can to do this like so:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [draw] (A) at (0,0) {demo text};
\node [draw] (B) at (0,-2) {demo text};
\draw ([xshift=1em]A.south) -- ([xshift=1em]B.north);
\draw ([xshift=-1em]A.south) -- ([xshift=-1em]B.north);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I have to set the anchor and shift every point. 
It seems to much for such a simple task.

Can you suggest a better way?

Cheers.

Answer (score 28):

The problem comes from the fact that the fixed node or coordinate values are immune to later transformations. For example, `scale=3` would also not work. Hence, the `xshift` works if the given coordinates are not fixed to a node or a coordinate i.e. something like `(3,4)` would work.

If the path that you draw is not related to the bounding box of the figure you can enforce the shift at the low level drawing because the following does not influence the bounding box.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [draw] (A) at (0,0) {demo text};
\node [draw] (B) at (0,-2) {demo text};
\draw[transform canvas={xshift=1em}] (A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: You can't apply this solution to circular nodes...

Comment: @PaulGaborit Indeed that is also a problem. However then it's not just a shift but also a stretch.

Comment: To me, for squared nodes, this is the best solution: simple and readable. For circle-like nodes, thumbs up for the angle approach of @Gonzalo Medina, first because it works, second because it is natural to reason in angle terms for circles.

Comment: The answer should be accepted by now :)

Answer (score 17):

One possibility:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [draw] (A) at (0,0) {demo text};
\node [draw] (B) at (0,-2) {demo text};
\draw (A.215) -- (B.145);
\draw (A.325) -- (B.35);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And another one, using this time the perpendicular coordinate system, so only two angles are necessary:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [draw] (A) at (0,0) {demo text};
\node [draw] (B) at (0,-2) {demo text};
\draw (A.215) -- (A.215|-B.north);
\draw (A.325) -- (A.325|-B.north);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I could not find any coordinate system in the manual that uses this syntax. Maybe you could briefly state what `(A.215)` means here?

Comment: For squared nodes I prefer the "transform canvas" of percusse, but for circle-like ones this makes a lot of sense. @Alexander: read "13.2.3 Node Coordinate System" on manual v.2.10 ("/tikz/cs/angle=<degrees>" and the shortcuts at the end of section).

Comment: @antonio topologically, a circle, a square, a rectangle, are basically "the same thing" (they are homeomorphic), so for a mathematician using the same approach for all of them is natural :)

Comment: For anyone else who stumbles upon this: `(A.215)` means 215 degrees as seen from A. `(A.north)` is the same as `(A.90)`, `(A.west)` is the same as `(A.180)`, so on and so forth.

Answer (score 12):

Here is a solution via `double`. I superimposed dashed lines to compare your solution (black) to mine (red).

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=1pt]
\node [draw] (A) at (0,0) {demo text};
\node [draw] (B) at (0,-2) {demo text};
% method via double
\draw[red,double=white,double distance=2em-\pgflinewidth] (A) -- (B);
% your method
\draw[dashed] ([xshift=1em]A.south) -- ([xshift=1em]B.north);
\draw[dashed] ([xshift=-1em]A.south) -- ([xshift=-1em]B.north);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Triple variation

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\tikzset{
  triple/.style={
    double=white,double distance=2em-\pgflinewidth,
    postaction={draw},
  },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=1pt]
\node [draw] (A) at (0,0) {demo text};
\node [draw] (B) at (0,-2) {demo text};
% method via triple
\draw[red,triple] (A) -- (B);
% your method (triple variation)
\draw[dashed] ([xshift=1em]A.south) -- ([xshift=1em]B.north);
\draw[dashed] ([xshift=-1em]A.south) -- ([xshift=-1em]B.north);
\draw[dashed] (A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @HarishKumar we can define a `triple` style. :-)

Comment: That will be a value addition (with a note on how to make it general -- 4, 5 ...) `:-)`